# NEAR FunctionCall `args` field

Tags: blockchain, near

In the `near_primitives::views`, the `args` field on the `FunctionCall` is represented as a `String` type. From the chain data model, which is `transaction::Action::FunctionCall`, its `args` field there is a `Vec.

The question is, does this `args` field will always content a valid JSON payload as the content? We assume the answer is probably a `No` since the underlying field contains pure bytes.

In which circumstances this would a valid JSON string and in which circumstances it would be a binary format?

Finally, if binary format is possible (likely), how is it possible to decode it? Is this in developers hand and could be any binary format?

See

- https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/14711926391d3ec1d23116658a295a62e77bc701/core/primitives/src/views.rs#L768

- https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/14711926391d3ec1d23116658a295a62e77bc701/core/primitives/src/transaction.rs#L113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases `args` will be base64 encoded JSON string.

Here's an example of how we decode them on NEAR Indexer for Explorer side.

```
ActionView::FunctionCall {
    method_name,
    args,
    gas,
    deposit,
} => {
    if let Ok(decoded_args) = base64::decode(args) {
        if let Ok(mut args_json) = serde_json::from_slice(&decoded_args) {
            escape_json(&mut args_json);
            arguments["args_json"] = args_json;
        }
    }
```

> Is this in developers hand and could be any binary format?

Yes.

Rainbow Bridge-related transactions have borsh-serialized args which are not possible to decode into JSON.

ref: https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer/blob/master/src/models/serializers.rs#L94-L103

Answer (score 1):

`args` are not limited to any format at all, they are just binary blob. What you see in the `views.rs` is partially serialized data where [`args` are expected to be in base64 encoding](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/14711926391d3ec1d23116658a295a62e77bc701/core/primitives/src/views.rs#L803) thus it is a `String` (thus, it is always base64 data there; be it JSON, Borsh-serialized data, or just raw binary blob, e.g. PNG image)